# After Login User redirect different Page according to Role In asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

but it's not working how to solve this problem

[image: This Image show the My Project Folder Admin, User and Customer]

Main Web.Config file which contain all information about Authentication membership and role manager

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies"  path="/"

    loginUrl="Login/default.aspx"  protection="All" timeout="30">
  </forms>
</authentication>

<membership defaultProvider="Demo_MemberShipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="Demo_MemberShipProvider"

        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"

        connectionStringName="cs"

        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"

        enablePasswordReset="true"

        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"

        applicationName="/"

        requiresUniqueEmail="false"

        passwordFormat="Hashed"

        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"

        minRequiredPasswordLength="5"

        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"

        passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true"

cookieName="TBHROLES" defaultProvider="Demo_RoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="cs"

    applicationName="/" name="Demo_RoleProvider"

    type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web,
              Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>



      <!--Admin Web.Config-->
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin" />
    <deny roles="User, Customer"/>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
  <!--Customer Web.Config-->
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin, User, Customer" />
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
  <!--User Web.Config-->
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin, User" />
    <deny roles="Customer"/>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
```

This is Login button Code for login

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password) == true)
    {
        Login1.Visible = true;
        Session["user"] = User.Identity.Name;
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, true);
    }
    else
    {

        Response.Write("Invalid Login");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password) == true)
        {
            Login1.Visible = true;
            Session["user"] = User.Identity.Name;

            var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(Login1.UserName);
            var userIdentity = new GenericIdentity(Login1.UserName);
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(userIdentity, userRoles);

            Context.User = principal;

            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                Response.Redirect("~/ThePageForAdmin");

            if (User.IsInRole("User"))
                Response.Redirect("~/ThePageForUser");

            if (User.IsInRole("Customer"))
                Response.Redirect("~/ThePageForCustomer");
        }
        else
        {

            Response.Write("Invalid Login");
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry this Error occur  The type or namespace name 'GenericPrincipal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Thank's for your reply but it is not working it still in the login page not redirecting the page according to user role